# Rails 3 - render inline form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

We use `render inline:` in `index` view rendering:

```
<%= render inline: ERB.new(@erb_code).result(binding) %>
```

Here `@erb_code` returns a string for `index` view code for rendering. The code worked fine until a `form_tag` was added to `@erb_code`. The error is:

```
(erb):8: syntax error, unexpected ')'
...@project.id), method: :get do ).to_s); _erbout.concat "\r\n\...
...                               ^
(erb):63: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting ')'
; _erbout.force_encoding(__ENCODING__)
                                      ^
```

Here is the `form_tag` code added:

```
<%= form_tag onboard_engine_configs_path(format: "csv", :project_id => @project.id), method: :get do %>
          <%= label_tag(:from_release, "Release") %>
          <%= select_tag(:from_release, options_for_select(releases.select('id, name').map{|r| [r.name, r.id]})) %>      
          <%= submit_tag 'CSV' %>
  <% end %>
```

If rendering @erb_code directly, then there is no error.

The index.erb.html is:

```
<%= render partial: 'form_list', locals: {models: @onboard_engine_configs} %>
```

We know the problem is with the `render inline:`. Tried `render inline: @erb_code` and the error is the same. How to escape `form_tag` in `render inline:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here the `render inline` works:

```
<%= render inline: @erb_code, locals: {models: models} %>
```

Here action view's rendering is used (instead of ruby's ERB) and variable `models` is passed in again within `locals` to the inline.

Answer (score 1):

Try to enclose your form_tag in brackets

```
<%= form_tag(onboard_engine_configs_path(format: "csv", :project_id => @project.id), method: :get) do %>
```